# Meteor.js, I cannot display a Template using Meteor Session

Tags: meteor, session-variables

here is my issue: I have a very basic main layout where you would click an item from a  list of items and see the content of that clicked item displayed on a diffrent section of the page. I know there a some example of that that I could copy but since I am learning Meteor, I wanted to complete it myself.

here is the temmplate.js to get the session and return the content:

```
 Template.lelementItem.events({
    'click .clic': function(){
        Session.set("clickedItem", this.ladescription);
    }
  });

    Template.lelementItem.afficheDescription = function() { 
        return Session.get("clickedItem");
    };
```

Here is the template.html

```
 <template name="afficheDescription">
    {{clickedItem}}
    </template>
```

If I output the content in an alert like this it shows the content but I cannot output the content in the right place using template:

```
Template.lelementItem.events({
    'click .clic': function(){
        alert(this.ladescription);
    }
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
Template.lelementItem.afficheDescription = function() { 
    return Session.get("clickedItem");
};
```

with

```
Template.afficheDescription.clickedItem = function() { 
    return Session.get("clickedItem");
};
```

In the first case, you're adding a helper `afficheDescription` to the template `lelementItem`. You want to add a helper `clickedItem` to the template `afficheDescription`.

Comment: It worked, thank you. 

Do you know of any resource where I can furnther my learning to better undertand Sessions in Meteor. The meteor Docs has something but far too abstract to the rest of US NOOB. :-)